# Compare the state of my system before vs. after software installation

Tags: windows, installation, comparison

I'd like to compare the state of my system before and after the installation of a given software. I've tried to do it with Windows System State Analyzer but the diff hangs after a few minutes and throws the message:

> insert deleted keys

Then it works for hours (like 12h) without producing any output. I've got two questions:

- Is this the normal behavior?
- Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I do it manually:
cmd as administrator - dir c:\ /s >files-before.txt
regedit - file - export - all - registry-before.txt
install,
make files/registry-after.txt
and check differences in kdiff3

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at [System Explorer](http://systemexplorer.net/).

You can create a system snapshot, install your software, then take another snapshot and compare the two.

You can also save as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Total Uninstall](https://www.martau.com/). It's not free, but if you run it before you install a program and then again afterwards or use it to start the installation program, then it will generate a report showing all of the registry and file changes that have been made to the system during the installation of a program. It can export a text file listing those changes. It can also be [used to transfer programs from one computer to another](https://www.martau.com/document/transfer-programs-to-new-pc.php).